# ckEditor: no p and no br

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to allow basic `<strong>`, `<em>` and lists with ckeditor.

However I want NO `<br>` and no paragraph tags, as I `nlb2` my content and I want it to be essentially naked.

Via google I found that I could do:

```
$(function() {
    $('#description').ckeditor({
        enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
        shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
        toolbar:[['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink'], ['UIColor']]
});
```

However, that still ends up with paragraph tags in it.

So a bit of searching and I found this: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

However I have no idea how to implement that into my jQuery call.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe CKEditor provides functionality to restrict certain tags.  You could achieve this on the server-side though, if you use PHP there is [`strip_tags()`](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

There is an alternative free editor (I prefer this one) called [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) that does provide much more customization, including a [valid elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/valid_elements) setting.

Comment: I figured this would be the case, wanted to avoid doing it though.

Comment: @azz0r Please read my latest update.  Not sure if changing editors is an option for you.

Comment: Thanks, Ive implimented it via     tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "exact", elements: "description",
valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b"
    }); 

however it wraps everything in paragraph tags :/

Comment: @azz0r Even after you hit save?  I believe that is when it goes through the stripping process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue, in sort after you hit save, it will save out a blank p tag or just a break tag.

Seems like server side is the way to go (besides using tinymce) sucks though.